# How a browser is able to pesent unreadable code in right way

Tags: parsing, web, encode

I met a problem when i try to get the content of following link:

```
www.aaspassindia.com/news.aspx?newsid=267 &city=Rajkot
```

the content is written in Gujarati ,and it can be presented rightly in browser, but when you try to copy content or see it in the source html code,you will find that the content is actually unreadable codes.

So how browser is able represent it? How  a browser is able to present  unreadable code  in right way ?

Comment: This probably has to do with the font that is being used to display the characters.

Comment: Thx,the problem is from the font

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from fonts,the fonts used in the website is a little bit weird,and it is defined in label